# Returning key pair value from array of objects in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more modern approach to this instead of using a nested loop with $.each? I have static data that represents what I am receiving in my JSON object and I'm trying to build a table from the data but I am not able to find out why the rows do not line up like the static example included.

```js
var data = [{
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryTitle": "Title one"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "categoryTitle": "Title two"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 3,
    "categoryTitle": "Title three"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 4,
    "categoryTitle": "Title four"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 5,
    "categoryTitle": "Title five"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 6,
    "categoryTitle": "title six"
  }
];


$("#result").append("<table><tr><td>CategoryId</td><td>Value</td></tr>");
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
  $.each(val, function(key, name) {
    $("#result").append("<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr>")
  });
});
$("#result").append("</table>");
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

table tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: #666666
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>

<h3>Result should look like this below</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>categoryId</td>
    <td>categoryTitle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Title two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Title three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Title four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: *"I am not able to find out why the rows do not line up like the static example included."* You are creating a new row for every property: `$("#result").append("<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + name + "</td></tr>")`. If you want one row per object, then you have to create the row element in the outer loop.

Comment: Side note, you are creating dom elements, not html markup.  Every time you append an element to the page, it will create a dom element.  So just because you appending html without a closing tag, does not mean the dom will wait for you to close the element.  Again, because you are not appending html.

Answer (score 0):

There you go :)

You dont need key, since the key you want to display is actually a value.

```js
var data = [{
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryTitle": "Title one"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "categoryTitle": "Title two"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 3,
    "categoryTitle": "Title three"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 4,
    "categoryTitle": "Title four"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 5,
    "categoryTitle": "Title five"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 6,
    "categoryTitle": "title six"
  }
];

var $table = $("<table>");
var $head_row = $("<tr>");
$head_row.append( "<th>CategoryId</th>" );
$head_row.append( "<th>Value</th>" );
$table.append($head_row);

$.each(data, function(i, val) {
  var $row = $('<tr>');
  $.each(val, function(key, name) {
    $row.append( "<td>" + name + "</td>" );
  });
  $table.append($row);
  
});
$("#result").append($table);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

table tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: #666666
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than appending to the element on the page multiple times, limit the number of times you alter the DOM by building your html first and then appending it all at once.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryTitle": "Title one"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "categoryTitle": "Title two"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 3,
    "categoryTitle": "Title three"
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 4,
    "categoryTitle": "Title four"
  }
];

var result = "<table><tr><td>CategoryId</td><td>Value</td></tr>";

data.forEach(function(category) {
  result += "<tr><td>" + category.categoryId + "</td><td>" + category.categoryTitle + "</td></tr>";
});

result += "</table>";

$("#result").append(result);
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #cecece;
}

table tr:first-of-type {
  background-color: #666666
}

td {
  border: 1px solid grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>

<h3>Result should look like this below</h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>categoryId</td>
    <td>categoryTitle</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Title one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Title two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Title three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Title four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It is also important to be aware that when you append to the DOM, you are not appending HTML.

```
$(selector).append('<table>');
$(selector).append('</table>');
```

When you perform these two statements, **each** statement is creating a new table element in the DOM.  This is because when you append markup, it gets converted into DOM Elements immediately.  So if you want to create DOM Elements that are properly nested within their parents, you **must** give it the complete markup all at once.  This is provided that you are giving it markup to append, and not already created DOM Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Building the table first by way of declaring a variable and adding to it before finally appending it to the dom was the better way. Adding the row outside the second $.each as pointed out by Felix Kling was necessary in order to create the rows I was getting blocked on.

```js
    var data = [{
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryTitle": "Title one"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryTitle": "Title two"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 3,
        "categoryTitle": "Title three"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 4,
        "categoryTitle": "Title four"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 5,
        "categoryTitle": "Title five"
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 6,
        "categoryTitle": "title six"
      }
    ];

var tbl = "<table width='100%'>";

tbl += '<tr><th>Category ID</th><th>Category Title</th></tr>';
 $.each(data, function(i, val) {
  tbl += '<tr>'
  $.each(val, function(key, name) {
    tbl += '<td>' + name + '</td>'
  });
 });
 tbl += '</table>'
 
 $("#result").append(tbl);
```

```css
    table {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #cecece;
    }

    table tr:first-of-type {
      background-color: #666666
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid grey
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="result"></div>
```